# Package installer doesn't ask to click on "Done" or "Open" after updating app programmatically

Tags: android, android-intent, auto-update, android-package-managers, packageinstaller

My app has Auto-Update feature. I install apk file using this code:

```
Uri uri;
Intent intent;

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
    uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider", file);
    intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSTALL_PACKAGE);
    intent.setData(uri);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
} else {
    uri = Uri.fromFile(file);
    intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
}

context.startActivity(intent);
```

The problem is that in **api 24 or higher** Android package installer doesn't ask to click on *"Done"* or *"Open"* after updating completed and dialog will be closed without any questions or any messages.

I need package installer ask what to do like

[image: This Picture].

Comment: Why is this a problem?

Comment: @CommonsWare: User tries to update app and suddenly the dialog closes without any questions or any messages. it is not expected. User must inform about completing update process and he/she should have choices to open the app or not.

Comment: AFAIK, Google changed the flow to not show that screen. That's Google's decision to make, since it is their operating system.

Comment: @CommonsWare: So you mean there is really no way and this is a waste of time to try to find a solution?

Comment: AFAIK, you have no control over the behavior, if that is what you mean. The behavior of `ACTION_INSTALL_PACKAGE` and `ACTION_VIEW` are up to their implementers (Google, and secondarily device manufacturers/custom ROM developers). There is no `EXTRA_PLEASE_SHOW_OPEN_OR_DONE_ACTIVITY` that I know of in the Android SDK. The behavior that you cite is for the devices that you tested; other devices can behave differently.

Comment: @CommonsWare: But [CafeBazzar Iranian App Market](http://cafebazaar.ir/) has done it. when you update an app in _CafeBazaar_, the old behavior occures on Android 7.0 and you have two choices to click on **"Done"** or **"Open"**.

Comment: Did you found any solution?

Comment: @H.Fa8 No, I didn't! What about you?

Comment: @AlirezaNoorali You should use debug version when debug version installed before,  and if release version installed you should use release version for update.

Comment: @H.Fa8 I think you didn't read the question carefully. The subject of the question is something else